# How can I pass the kendoDropdown value and the kendoDatepicker value from a partial view to another partial view without using model or ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using kendo dropdownlist to select status and kendo datepicker to select date in a partial view.
After clicking on submit button, I want to pass both these values to another partial view (../Test/_Result). How can I achieve this without using model or ajax?

Answer (score 0):

If it all in one page without reload. The only way is js. You need save parameter in javascript value, then pass to second partial. I can write code if you need.
You can get values from kendo with kendo events.